# Is this a crash or a planned shutdown? "The system is going down for system halt NOW!"

Tags: linux, centos

Linux noob. This message was in my SSH console this morning.

> The system is going down for system halt NOW!

Did an admin shut this VM down or did it crash?

Comment: Please comment before down-voting. I really don't understand why this is a bad question.

Comment: you may find the answer in /var/log/messages

Comment: Thanks. I take it its not a straight-forward thing to answer.

Comment: /var/log/messages is a log file on your system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system was powered off by the System Administrator. In Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6 /sbin/shutdown prints this message.

```
$ strings /sbin/shutdown | grep 'halt NOW!'
The system is going down for halt NOW!
```

If you are interested in the code: [shutdown.c warning_message() function](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/view/head:/util/shutdown.c#L581), [shutdown.c main() calls warning_message()](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/view/head:/util/shutdown.c#L402)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I must have wrote my own answer as you were answering, too. I'll let voting decide who gets the tick.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question.

According to information in this link, the above 'halt' message is broadcast to sessions during a shutdown, `shutdown -h now`.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=36485

The `-h` means halt in Linux parlance, an unfamiliar term to Windows users, and does not mean something unplanned and bad has happened. Halt is a shutdown without an ACPI power-off message, which is not really a concept in Windows.